# The getContact api call keeps running and does not throw an error. What is the fix?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, async-await, get

```
//@desc Get contact
//@route GET api/contacts/:id
//@access public
const getContact = asyncHandler(async (req,res) => {
    const ret = await Contact.findById(req.params.id)
    console.log(ret); // Line 6
    if(!(await ret)){
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error("Contact not found");
    }
    res.status(200).json(ret);
});
```

The above code is the api call, I try to retrieve a contact with an ID 'id' passed through the params.

errorHandler:

```
// In this componenet, all errors of this application will be dealt with.

//Import constants for cleaner error handling
const constants = require("../constants");

// Errors consist of error, response, request and the next function
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) =>{
    // When an error is caused, we check the status of the response and determine the cause
    const status = res.statusCode? res.statusCode : 500;
    switch(status){
        case 400:
            res.json({
                title: "BAD REQUEST",
                message: err.message,
                stackTrace: err.stack
            });
            break;
        case 404:
            res.json({
                title: "NOT FOUND",
                message: err.message,
                stackTrace: err.stackTrace
            });
            break;
        case 403:
            res.json({
                title: "FORBIDDEN REQUEST",
                message: err.message,
                stackTrace: err.stackTrace
            });
            break;
        case 401:
            res.json({
                title: "UNAUTHORIZED",
                message: err.message,
                stackTrace: err.stackTrace
            });
            break;
        case 500:
            res.json({
                title: "SERVER ERROR",
                message: err.message,
                stackTrace: err.stackTrace
            });
            break;
        default:
            // console.log("res - ", res)
            // console.log("req - ", req)
            // console.log("err", err)

            console.log("Error Handler working...");
            break;
    };
};

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

Routes:

```
//Handle all requests - get, put, post and delete

// Import all express functionalities
const server = require("express");

// Create a router through express
const router = server.Router();

// - After creating all routes, we need to import controller functions
const {getAllContacts, createContact, getContact, updateContact, deleteContact} = require("../Controllers/allControllers");
// We need to route all the api calls
router.route("/").get(getAllContacts).post(createContact);

router.route("/:id").get(getContact).put(updateContact).delete(deleteContact);

// Expose all routes
module.exports = router;
```

Mongoose schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const contactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter the name"]
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter the email"]
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter the number"]
    }
},
{ 
    timestamps: true 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Contact", contactSchema);
```

The happy path works but when I try to send an id that is not stored in a document in my collection(mongoDB), the api call keeps running. The errorHandler automatically calls the default case and carries on with execution. Line 6 does not log anything.

This is my first project using node and express. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!(await ret))` is wrong. The await keyword returns a promise and is not used within the if block. Ofc line 6 doesn't log anything because ret is null. So, check the ret like this

```
if(!ret){
  res.status(404);
  throw new Error("Contact not found");
}
```

Comment: My initial code only used ret. I was messing around with awaits until I realized I was wrong.

Comment: The actual problem was not with the code at all. It was with the ID I passed to the get method. I was not aware that mongo uses a 24 character fixed length string for _id and I was trying to pass 23 character string which caused the unknown error

Comment: Then you should check the id with regex. Something like this `const objectIdRegex=/^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i` and `if(!objectIdRegex.test(req.params.id)) return new Error();`.